# Having constraints into constraints

Tags: c#, constraints

I have this scenario:

```
public abstract class UblParser<TDto, TUbl> where TUbl : UblBaseDocumentType
                                            where TDto: DtoB
{
    public abstract TUbl ParseFrom(TDto dto);
    public abstract TDto ParseTo(TUbl document);
}
```

How do I declare a class using a constraint inside another constraint like this?

```
public class UblConverter<TParser> where TParser : UblParser<TDto, TUbl>
                                   where TUbl : UblBaseDocumentType
                                   where TDto : DtoB
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to include all of the generic types in your class definition.

```
public class UblConverter<TParser, TDto, TUbl> where TParser : UblParser<TDto, TUbl> 
                                               where TUbl : UblBaseDocumentType 
                                               where TDto : DtoB 
{
    //...
}
```